# Retrieving certain PFObjects depending on an array

Tags: arrays, swift, parse-platform, pfquery, pfobject

I've looked all over and people say that using `whereKey: equalTo:` will work in an array but for some reason it doesn't for me. I'm trying to have users search for a tag and all post that contain that tag appear. when I remove `whereKey: equalTo:` I get all results but with it I get nothing. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is the code that takes care of creating and querying the class.

```
import Foundation

class WallPost: PFObject, PFSubclassing {

@NSManaged var post: String
@NSManaged var user: PFUser
@NSManaged var tags: [String]

init(post: String, user: PFUser, tags: [String]) {
    super.init()

    self.post = post
    self.user = user
    self.tags = tags
}

override init() {
    super.init()
}



override class func query() -> PFQuery?{
    let query = PFQuery(className: parseClassName())
    query.includeKey("user")
    query.whereKey("tags", equalTo: "rock")




    query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
    return query
}

class func parseClassName() -> String {
    return "POST"
}

override class func initialize(){
    var onceToken: dispatch_once_t = 0
    dispatch_once(&onceToken) {
        self.registerSubclass()
    }
}
}
```

[I've added a screenshot of the parse class here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRMb7.png)

Comment: Is tags the name of the array stored on parse, or how is your database set up?

Comment: @pbush25 the name of the array.

Answer (score 0):

If "tags" is the name of the array in parse, then you need to add this parameter to your query:

```
query.whereKey("rock", containedIn: "tags")
```

Comment: `containedIn: ` takes a parameter of [AnyObject] so I get an error telling me I can't covert string to [AnyObject]

Comment: You're right, sorry about that. Do you have a local copy of the array?

Comment: Sorry, I misread what you were asking, and you're right, you should be able to do this with the `equalTo`. Can you add a picture of the Parse class in question so we can see?

Comment: I added the class to the original post